# Close all firefox windows on windows and mac using python -- no selenium

Tags: python, windows, macos, firefox

I want to programmatically close and open Firefox browser using python

1. on windows I am using `os.system("taskkill /im firefox.exe /f")`. But this does not close all windows in win 8. Please suggest a sure way to kill all open windows of firefox and also kill any background processes associated with firefox
2. Second question is that can I do similar thing in mac without using selenium or any other overhead

Comment: On mac, use `pkill firefox`.

Comment: how do i use this in python?

Comment: `os.system("pkill firefox")` if you prefer `os.system`, or use the `subprocess` package.

Comment: pkill firefox doesnt close firefox in my mac. it gives me output 32512 for os.system("taskkill /im firefox.exe /f")   and os.system("pkill firefox.exe") gives 256.